# How to check the linearity of continuous variable in linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, continuous-data, linearity

I'm doing a linear mixed model using lme.

In my adjustement factors, I have a continuous varaible (named X1). And I want to check the linearity of this variable using a spline function or a fractional polynomial but I don't succeed.

Can someone help me ? How to do that ?

Ex with spline :

```
lme(Y ~ T + X + pspline(X1, 4), data = df, random = ~ T | SUBJECT )
```

But then, I don't know how to conclude for the linearity.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for linearity using natural cubic splines from the **splines** package and a likelihood ratio test - note that you need to fit the model using maximum likelihood (not restricted maximum likelihood) because of the different fixed-effects parts. For example,

```
library("splines")
fm0 <- lme(Y ~ T + X + X1, data = df, random = ~ T | SUBJECT, method = "ML")
fm1 <- lme(Y ~ T + X + ns(X1, 4), data = df, random = ~ T | SUBJECT, method = "ML")
anova(fm0, fm1)
```

Comment: What is the difference between using a spline function like pspline(X1,4) and a natural cubic spline like in your example ?

If the likelihood ratio test is significant, does this mean that the variable is not linear ?

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Indeed, if the likelihood ratio test is significant it means that the model with the spline provides a better fit to the data than the model with the linear term.

Comment: Dimitris, what strategy do you recommend for choosing the degrees of freedom for the ns() term in an lme model?

Comment: Check Section 2.4 (slides 65-57) in my course notes for my suggestions: http://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/CE08.pdf